# Performance between non-clustered index and composite primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am changing the primary key of a SQL Server 2014 database from a composite key containing columns of these types:

```
VARCHAR(10), INT, DATETIME
```

to a composite key containing

```
INT, DATETIME
```

where the `INT` in the second key is a new column a hash of the previous combination of `VARCHAR(10)`, `INT`. I can't change the primary key just yet so after adding the new column, I created an index what would in the future be the new primary key (`INT, DATETIME`):

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX MyIndex 
     ON MyTable(MyIdCol, MyDateCol)
```

At this point, I switched my readers to fetch data using this index rather than the primary key. Everything works but the performance is severely degraded (more than double the time).

At this point, I experimented with making (`INT, DATETIME`) the new primary key. Query speed improved by 30-40% but I honestly thought it would have been a lot faster to query on this new primary key than the old one which has a `VARCHAR` in it (of course I could have messed something up in my benchmarks - the DB schema is quite involved and takes 24h to set up the testcases).

Unfortunately, I drop the primary key in production just yet - I need a phase where I have the old primary key and the new unique index simultaneously so I will need to get similar performance on lookups on this index. I need direction on what to look at. If I'm honest I don't fully understand why querying on an `INT,DATETIME` even just as an index and not primary key is so much slower than `VARCHAR,INT,DATETIME` primary key.

Comment: Can you get actual execution plans for the queries and paste them to this site:  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Any execution plans? Select code? Table DDL?

Comment: @MJH The query is executed as XML. Here are the actual execution plans: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJzNLaRwm

Comment: @MJH This is the execution plan when querying using the index with what will become the new primary key.

Comment: @IvanStarostin https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJzNLaRwm (see above)

Comment: How are you creating the hash for your int? Perhaps it's too similar and causing an unbalanced b-tree in the index.

Comment: @SteveFord it is a sequential number. I have the mapping (VARCHAR,INT) to (INT) in a table and I just get a new, sequentially increasing INT for each pair of (VARCHAR,INT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

How much slower is "slower"?  When searching through a non-clustered index, the database engine needs to find the row references in the index (quite fast) and then load the data pages to fetch the row.

When searching using a clustered index, there is no need to load the data pages.

The difference is likely to be much more noticeable when fetching multiple rows, because the clustered index will have the data on the same data pages.  The non-clustered index is likely to be fetching from a different page for each item being retrieved (up to a point).

You can compare the difference in performance by fetching only columns in the index.  This might not be what you want, but it is a viable performance comparison.  These should be similar between the two indexes.

This *might* explain the difference in performance.  If so, then this is nothing to worry about, because it is the expected overhead when not using a clustered index.  In general, this is relatively big for queries that are fast and less important for queries that are slower.